# How are 買 and 売 related?

Tags: kanji

It has always struck me as strange that 買 "buy" and 売 "sell", which are antonyms, have the same *on*-reading バイ. A few questions:

1. Is there some logic (possibly stemming from the Chinese use of these characters) behind the readings being so similar?
2. How are the characters 買 and 売 related? Is one derived from the other?

(This post is inspired by the comments on [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17498/3437), which ought to find their way into a proper answer rather than languishing in the comments section.)

Comment: The question applies equally well in Chinese – and you might get more answers if you pose it as such.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### The Chinese part

The answer to this question ultimately goes back into the Chinese from whence these characters originally came.

> ​1. Is there some logic (possibly stemming from the Chinese use of these characters) behind the readings being so similar?

The *on'yomi* come from Chinese.  Both 売 (selling) and 買 (buying) are simply two sides of the same activity, so it kind of makes sense that they're almost the same word: 売 (in Mandarin, *mài* with a high falling tone), 買 (*mǎi* with a low tone rising slightly at the end).

> ​2. How are the characters 買 and 売 related? Is one derived from the other?

Courtesy snailboat:  Yes, one is derived from the other.  The modern Japanese kanji 売 is a 新字体{しんじたい}, a simplified form.  The old character is 賣, which is 士 over 買.  The 士 element here is itself simplified from older 出 "*to put out*", so 売(賣) = 出＋買 = "*to put out for buying*" = "*to sell*".

#### The Japanese part

This isn't part of the original question, but in the interests of completeness, we should also look at the etymologies of the Japanese words *kau* "to buy" and *uru* "to sell".

- Japanese 買{か}う is, at its root, the same word as 代う, 換う, 替う, 交う, all かう with a root meaning of "to trade, to swap, to exchange". By extension, these are the roots of かわる・かえる "to change, to turn [into]", and probably also かえる・かえす "to turn back, to return".  See also [the Gogen Allguide entry for 買う](http://gogen-allguide.com/ka/kau.html).

  かう derives from older かふ.  This seems to be related to 食{く}う (older くふ) "to eat, to put into one's mouth" and 請{こ}う・乞{こ}う (older こふ) "to ask [for], to request".  All three are semantically related to ideas of *getting* or *taking in*.

  Much more speculatively, these *inward* semantics make me wonder if these might be cognate with 来{く} (modern 来{く}る), with the final ふ perhaps the well-known auxiliary that attaches to the *mizenkei* and indicates repeated or continuous action.  If so, かふ would meet the expected form of the *mizenkei* (with an *a* sound), but くふ and こふ would not, leaving significant holes in this theory.
- Japanese 売{う}る, meanwhile, is cognate with 得{え}る (also read as うる) "to get, to acquire", from the idea of *getting* money (or something else desired) in exchange for the item sold.  See also [the Gogen Allguide entry for 売る](http://gogen-allguide.com/u/uru.html).

Comment: To expand on the Chinese part, it is thought that in Old Chinese (spoken 2000-3000 years ago) the two words 買 /*mˁrajʔ/ and 賣 /*mˁrajʔ-s/ were related by a final -s consonant. This paper discusses some of the possible grammatical functions of -s: http://www.ling.sinica.edu.tw/files/publication/j2012_1_02_6180.pdf

Answer (score 3):

It's more obvious when you're looking at the non-simplified character for 売, 賣; the thing on top is 出 originally, which makes sense, but later reduced to 士. So, 賣/売 is indeed derived from 買.

Related, you can typically get to an etymology of Chinese characters just by typing them into Google by their lonesome.